# How to handle Permission Pop-ups using Selenium WebDriver in Headless Mode

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, geolocation, headless

[web application image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdTp0.jpg)
I'm currently working on Selenium WebDriver automation with Python, focusing on handling permission pop-ups in headless mode on a Linux machine. Specifically, I want to handle the location permission alert and allow it to make my tests run smoothly.
In non-headless mode my code is working fine, But in the headless mode its not working.

This is the code that I am trying to allow the geo location permission in the headless mode.

chromedriver Version: 120.0.6099.109
selenium   4.15.2
pytest       7.4.3

```
def create_headless_chrome_driver():
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

# Allow geolocation
chrome_options.binary_location 
= CHROME_BINARY_PATH
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# Handling geolocation
chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')

# Configure content settings to disable notifications and geolocation
content_settings = {'notifications': 1, 'geolocation': 1}
profile = {'managed_default_content_settings': content_settings}
prefs = {'profile': profile}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

# Add arguments to disable notifications, geolocation, and media stream
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-geolocation')
chrome_options.add_argument('--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream')

service = ChromeService(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

return driver`
```

But its not working. I wanted to handle the geo location permission as allow so that I can move forward in the testing.

PS: Please handle the geolocation allowed, find image attachment as reference.

Comment: did you check https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/handle-permission-pop-ups#Mobile?